# Changing navbar link's hover color in small viewports (under the hamburger)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm attempting to customize a navbar using Bootstrap 4.2.1. I've managed to customize everything *except* the color of the **HOVER** link text that appears under the hamburger menu (on a small viewport). In a wider viewport, the CSS below does the trick to specify the link's hover color. What am I missing to be able to change the hover link text on a small viewport?

```
.navbar-custom .nav-item:focus .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .dropdown-item:hover, 
.navbar-custom .dropdown-item:focus {
        color: #000; }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

Use `@media` query syntax:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar-custom .nav-item:focus .nav-link,
    .navbar-custom .dropdown-item:hover, 
    .navbar-custom .dropdown-item:focus {
            color: #000; }
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for more

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. While implementing it, I discovered that I had another set of styles buried deep in the CSS at another media query that was preventing the navbar from styling the way I wanted. So you pushed me right where I needed to go. Thanks!